# How trigger field changes in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, django-orm

I have project written on Django. In another projects I use SQLAlchemy and I use very usefull method to trigger field change:

```
@event.listens_for(ClassName.field_name, 'set')
def func_name(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value == oldvalue:
        return
```

In my Django project I have `Order` class:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        ('Paid', 'Paid'),
        ('Not Paid', 'Not Paid')
    )
    EXECUTION_CHOICES = (
        ('Done', 'Done'),
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    status_of_execution = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=EXECUTION_CHOICES, default='In Progress')
    status_of_payment = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='Not Paid')
    client_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    admin_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

`status_of_execution` field change only in admin panel, so I want to trigger when this field change and do something if it change on value `Done`. But I doesn't find solution like in SQLAlchemy, because Django only have signals like "`pre_save`, `post_save` ..."

Can anyone know how can I resolve my problem using Django ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it only changes in the admin, you can override the [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) on the admin and check the form's `changed_data` list:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'status_of_execution' in form.changed_data:
            if form.cleaned_data['status_of_execution'] == 'Done':
                # do stuff
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pre_save` signals in Django.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Order)
def event_handler(instance, **kwargs):

        old_instance = Order.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        # Created not Updated
        return 

    if instance.status_of_execution != old_instance.status_of_execution:
        print('status_of_execution changed')
```